# Indexing content in Solr and Lucene and matching on concatenated email username

Tags: elasticsearch, search, solr, lucene

I'm indexing raw content into documents and in the case of a document containing an email such as  robby.pond@email.com I need to have a search for robbypond hit on the document.

Currently I'm using the ClassicTokenizer (using for special handling of phone numbers as well) and WordDelimiterGraphFilter and here is a simplified analyzer chain.

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

This generates the following tokens with all type EMAIL.

robbypondgmailcom robby pond gmail com

The problem is that I have a requirement that a search such as robbypond will hit on the document. Is there any existing filter or set of parameters that I can use to concatenate the robby and pond tokens and add a robbypond token to the token stream?

Comment: The Shingle Filter will concatenate successive tokens for you, with an optional separator: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_7/filter-descriptions.html#shingle-filter - but it will depend on how exact you need those matches to be (i.e. you'll lose the metadata about gmail.com being after `@`, so you'll also get `pondgmail` as a token).

Comment: @Robby Did you get a chance to go through my answer, feel free to comment if you have any doubts, its been quite some time so would be great if you can provide update :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [mapping char filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html), which is executed before the tokenizer and can replace the `.` with empty char, so that only relevant tokens are combined together as compare to `Shingles` which will be very costly.

An example setting to create such analyzer

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "char_filter": [
                        "replace_dots"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "char_filter": {
                "replace_dots": {
                    "type": "mapping",
                    "mappings": [
                        ". =>"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And use Analyze API to inspect test the tokens

POST /_analyze

```
{
    "text" : "robby.pond@email.com",
    "analyzer" : "my_analyzer"
}
```

And generated tokens

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "robbypond",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 10,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "emailcom",
            "start_offset": 11,
            "end_offset": 20,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```